# Python Quantlib ->TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Thirty360'

Tags: python, quantlib

I am trying to run the code below, but for some reason on 1 pc it runs normally,
on the 2nd one it fails with the below error message; what is the reason that on 1 pc it runs normally and on the 2nd one it fails?

the code source :http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-bond-modeling.html

```
!pip install QuantLib
import QuantLib as ql
todaysDate = ql.Date(15, 1, 2015)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate
spotDates = [ql.Date(15, 1, 2015), ql.Date(15, 7, 2015), ql.Date(15, 1, 2016)]
spotRates = [0.0, 0.005, 0.007]
dayCount = ql.Thirty360()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
interpolation = ql.Linear()
compounding = ql.Compounded
compoundingFrequency = ql.Annual
spotCurve = ql.ZeroCurve(spotDates, spotRates, dayCount, calendar, interpolation,
                             compounding, compoundingFrequency)
spotCurveHandle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spotCurve)


> TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function
> 'new_Thirty360'.   Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
>     QuantLib::Thirty360::Thirty360(QuantLib::Thirty360::Convention,Date
> const &)
>     QuantLib::Thirty360::Thirty360(QuantLib::Thirty360::Convention)
```

Comment: It looks like a problem connected with libraries. Does OS are the same on both PC you test it on?

Comment: have you checked to make sure both systems are running the same version of python?

Comment: win os/python 3.6.5,/quantlib 1.21 the code works, and win os/python 3.8.8/quantlib 1.28 the code fails

Comment: seems like its a problem with the versions, with 1.21,1.25 it works, but with the latest version 1.28 it doesn't.

Comment: have to specify the exact convention; ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.USA) in 1.28

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected in version 1.28, as per release notes (see https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/releases/tag/QuantLib-SWIG-v1.28). The default constructors are no longer available in the underlying C++ library, that deprecated them back in version 1.23.

The rationale is that there are several different 30/360 conventions. The default constructor used to pick one particular convention (namely, 30/360 bond basis) but this made it possible for a user to just specify 30/360 and get the wrong day counter unknowingly. Since this release, you need to specify the exact convention. If you want the exact behavior as before, replace `ql.Thirty360()` with `ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.BondBasis)`. If, instead, you realize that those were not the actual conventions you wanted, pass the correct convention to the constructor of the day counter.

The same applies to `ql.ActualActual()`, which used to default to ISDA but in 1.28 requires an explicit convention: `ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISDA)`